# How to copy members with const fields

Tags: c++, class, constants

I found a problem with this code:

```
struct Example
{
    const int k;
    Example(int k) : k(k) {}
};

struct Board
{
    Example table[4];
    Board() {} // ???
};
```

My question is how to initialize table variable. If I provide a default constructor, I won't be able to change this const field. Is there a workaround? I can't rely on copy constructor too.

Comment: "If I provide a default constructor, I won't be able to change this const field." - in what way are you expecting to be able to change the const field? Do you just want to specify the values when the `Board` is constructed, or do you want to be able to mutate it afterward?

Comment: If you need to change value of `k` later, why do you need the `const` field?

Comment: There are awkwardly many `k`s in that row...

Comment: I'd like to e.g. copy Board object later on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean the following?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    struct Example
    {
        const int k;
        Example(int k) : k(k) {}
    };

    struct Board
    {
        Example table[4];
        Board() : table { 1, 2, 3, 4 } {} // ???
    };

    Board b;

    for ( const auto &e : b.table ) std::cout << e.k << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Another approach is to define table as a static data member provided that it  will be initialized the same way for all objects of the class. For example

```
struct Example
{
    const int k;
    Example(int k) : k(k) {}
};

struct Board
{
    static Example table[4];
    Board() {} // ???
};

Example Board::table[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly initialize each element in the array with the constructor: `Board(): table{9, 8, 7, 6} {}`